# How can I set baseVariants for a multidomain TYPO3 v9?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

TYPO3 9.5.5
I have a multidomain website using a combination of multiple page trees and several languages per tree. I have one page tree delivering content in German. This one is available on domain.de, domain.at and domain.ch. Then more trees for domain.com, domain.nl and so on (as the content structure differs very much in different languages).

Now I want to set baseVariants for local development and stage servers. I have a site config like this:

```
rootPageId: 1
base: /
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://domain-de.local/'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: 'https://www.domain.de/'
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutschland
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
  -
    title: Österreichisch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: 'https://www.domain.at/'
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_AT.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Österreich
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: strict
    flag: at
```

As far as I understand the backend GUI, I can only define top level domain baseVariants as main entry point, everything beneath can then just be controlled by path like `/de/`, `/at/` and so on, right? In my setup, I would need 'https://domain-at.local/', but how can I set the target sys_language_uid for this variant (as they all will point to the default language of the first page tree)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not possible via the GUI but can be added in the yaml file directly.

```
rootPageId: 1
base: /
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://domain-de.local/'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
languages:

...

  -
    title: Austrian
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: 'https://www.domain.at/'
    baseVariants:
      -
        base: 'https://domain-at.local/'
        condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
    typo3Language: de-AT
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for this feature? At least, there is nothing about it on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html#configuration-properties

Comment: See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86303-VariantsForSitesBase.html